# How to select all occurences and replace one by one in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

On VSCode, it is possible to select occurences of a word one by one with `CTRL/CMD + D` or all at once with `CTRL+SHIFT+L`. 
With both those methods, however, you replace them all by the same value. I would like to know if there is a way to select all occurences and yet replace them one by one switching to the next one with `TAB` for example.
For instance, in the pug code below, I would like to select one "About Us" text, click on some keyboard shortcut to automatically select them all and then press TAB to replace the first one by "Homepage", the second one by "About Us", etc.
Thanks in advance!

```
li: a(href="#") About Us
li: a(href="#") About Us
li: a(href="#") About Us
li: a(href="#") About Us
```

```
li: a(href="#") Homepage
li: a(href="#") Careers
li: a(href="#") About Us
li: a(href="#") Contact
```

Comment: You can use `CTRL + F` then type the word you want to find and the replacement value. Then use `CTRL + ALT + ENTER` to replace all occurrences or `CTRL + SHIFT + &` to replace one by one. You also have shortcuts to switch between occurrences.